# R plotly how to make bar chart show each bar's label?

Tags: r, bar-chart, plotly

I have a horizontal stacked bar chart with 60 data rows (bars). For some reason I only see the labels for each bar in intervals (e.g. at 10, 20, 30, etc.). I would like to see it being labeled for each bar.

My layout is set as the following

```
layout(barmode = 'stack',
    xaxis = list(title = ""),
    yaxis = list(title =""))
```

From all the examples I can find online, I can't see anything specific that people configure. So I wonder if this is due to the fact that I have 60 bars? Sorry in advance if this is trivial, but I couldn't find anything to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then all you would need is `tickvals` and `ticktext`. Please see the [reference page](https://plot.ly/r/reference/) for more details.

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(5)
df <- data.frame(x=round(runif(100,min = 0, max = 100), 0), y=runif(100,min = 0, max = 100))
plot_ly(df, x=~x, y=~y, type='bar')
```

This generates the following graph - 
[image]

However, if you use tickvals, ticktext like so `plot_ly(df, x=~x, y=~y, type='bar') %>% layout(xaxis=list(tickvals=df$x, ticktext=df$x))`, then you get  - 
[image]

Hope this answers the question.